# Question regarding basic set theory proofs: $f^{-1}(f(A))\not\subset A$ and $B \not \subset f(f^{-1}(B))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a couple of questions regarding some basic set theory proofs. More specifically:

Given the application $f: A \to B$

$f^{-1}(f(A))\not\subset A$  (I've written the proof when the application is injective of $f^{-1}(f(A))\subset A$, but I'd like to see the proof when it's not)

What I've been doing is as follows:

Let $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$ such that $f(x) \in f(A)$

Now, suppose $x \in A$, then it's proven.

On the other hand, suppose that $\exists y \in A : f(y) = f(x)$ Which could be the case with $y \not =  x$, since our application is not injective: then $y \in A$ but $x \not \in A$ necessarily.

So since $x$ may or may not be in $A$, then $f^{-1}(f(A))\not\subset A$

I'd like to know if what I wrote is valid. I have a very similar question for the following expression:

$B \not \subset f(f^{-1}(B))$ (Again, I've written the proof  of $B \subset f(f^{-1}(B))$ when its surjective, just wondering about the when it isn't proof when it isn't)

What I wrote was the following:

Let $x \in B$. Then $f^{-1}(x)$ may exist or it may not, (if it exists, then $x \in f(f^{-1}(B))$, but if it doesn't then $x \not \in f(f^{-1}(B))$. In conclusion, $B \not \subset f(f^{-1}(B))$

I'd really appreciate if you could tell me if these proofs are okay and if they aren't, where I went wrong and what should be fixed. I've basically been using these "properties" to write a lot of my basic set theory proofs, but proving the properties themselves seemed a bit more difficult. I also thought of using the more basic definitions of what the inverse image and stuff like that means in terms of a set, but I didn't get anywhere.

I do "undestand" these proofs when seeing them graphically with sets. It's the formal proofs that I'm more curious about. They seem like the hardest part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little bit confusing as phrased. Let's look at your first one. (The second one is similar, so I won't cover it.)  You seem to be trying to prove the following statement. I've changed the word "application" to "function", which is the standard English term.

> Given the function $f : A \to B$, then $f^{-1}(f(A)) \not \subset A.$

But you can't prove this, because, as stated, this is false. It is claiming that $f^{-1}(f(A)) \not \subset A$ is *always true*. But you know it is not always true because you immediately said that you proved the opposite $f^{-1}(f(A)) \subset A$ when $f$ is injective.  So you cannot prove that $f^{-1}(f(A)) \not \subset A$.

Instead, I believe the actual problem is something like

> *Find an example* of a function $f : A \to B$ where $f^{-1}(f(A)) 
> \not \subset A$.

Assuming this is the actual problem, then you need to give an example with particular sets $A$, $B$ and a function $f: A \to B$. Your writings are on the right track to finding an example; you just need to write down particular $A, B, f$ based on them.

Comment: I was looking for a proof as to why the statement $f^{-1}(f(A))\subset A$ isn't necessarily true, and using $\not\subset$ was definetly not the right notation. In any case I was wondering if my reasoning that $x$ may or may not be in $A$ is correct as to why $f^{-1}(f(A))$ may or may not be a subset of $A$.

(Again, I'd like to point out that what I meant is not what I wrote, so my bad)

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.